# How do I change the color of the separator between two slices of a pie chart in charts for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, pie-chart

I am using the Charts pod for iOS (github here: https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts ) to make a pie chart.

There is a 1 pixel line in between each slice of the chart. I would like to change the color of this line and/or make it thicker. However, I have not been able to find a way to do either of these things. How do I do this?

Here is what I tried unsuccessfully based on what I found in the `PieChartView` docs:

```
chart.tintColor = .blue
chart.maxAngle = 5
```

Comment: I think its slice space between each slice of the chart is `sliceSpace` between each slice. So, you can change that space using `yourPieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 5`

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its slice spacing between each slice of Pie Chart. If you want to change or increase that space then you can set space using `yourPieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

i think ther are no seprators you can change the background color of your view and set the corner radius to height / 2